# How to change the width of action bar tab in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs, android-navigation

I have searched more than 100 links but haven't found any working answer to the question.

I need to create variable number of tabs depending on the number of tabs I receive from previous activity. The tabs I get can have a length from 3 characters (All) to 24 characters. I am using the attached code for creating the tabs.

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

final int actionBarColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.green);
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(actionBarColor));

            for(int k = 0; k < tabs.length; k++) {
                TextView t = new TextView(browse_sub_category);

                t.setText(tabs[k]);
                t.setTextSize(18);
                t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                t.setSingleLine();
                t.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 0);
                t.setTypeface(myTypefaceLight);
                t.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                actionBar.addTab(
                        actionBar.newTab()
                        .setCustomView(t)
                        .setTabListener(browse_sub_category));              
            }

            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

By using the setCustomView, I can customize the textview but that doesn't impact the width of my tab. It is taking the default width. I want that if my tab name say 'All' require only 40dp to fit in then it should take only 40dp and if my tab name say 'Hello World' require 120dp then the tab should automatically take that width.

I have already tried customizing the textview by changing the width from LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT to numeric values. I have also tried to put a check like

```
if(tabs[k].length() <= 3) {
    tabWidth=40;
} else if((tabs[k].length() > 3) && (tabs[k].length() <= 6) {
    tabWidth=80;
} else {
    tabWidth=120;
}
```

but this impacts only the width textview not the width of tab.

I can set the maximum and minimum width of tab in styles.xml but that doesn't provide me the freedom to customize tab width based on tab name.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Action bar tabs are deprecated in the "L" Developer Preview and should remain deprecated in the next production release of Android. You may wish to consider moving to some other tab solution (`ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator, `FragmentTabHost`, etc.) or moving to another navigation pattern (e.g., navigation drawer).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. Guess I need to move to some other tab solution only if there is no solution available using action bar tabs.